# How to select the filed as date and time

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in `end_date` field like `29 August 2016 - 18:45`.

I want to write a query where `end_date` matches the current server date time.

I am using this

```
select * from round_dates where end_date = CURDATE()
```

`CURDATE()` matches the today date but I need to match the time also

Comment: `curdate()` return current date, `now()` return current datetime

Comment: I don't know how will that help you out on that. An error of one minute will not match the query. Do you really want to make that?

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from round_dates
where end_date =  DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%e %M %Y - %k:%i')
```

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` return the current datetime stamp of Mysql Server.
Whereas `CURDATE()` returns the date stamp only.

So, you can use this below Query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%e %M %Y - %k:%i') = NOW()
```

Comment: If end_date is indexed doing it this way will result in a table scan. The STR_TO_DATE would have to be applied to each row and compared.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) or date_format() functions to convert either the stored data to date format or the date format to the currently stored format.

Side note: I would rather do a one-off exercise of converting that field's data to standard MySQL datetime format, than trying to fix any queries relying on this field.

```
...where str_to_date(end_date,'%e %M %Y - %k:%i')=now()
```

Comment: This will result in a full table scan as the str_to_date function will have to be applied each time. Formatting now() will keep it as a constant value which will allow indices to be used.